# Why different results to two different ways of writing query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to understand why the following two SQL statements give different results.  The first works as expected, the second produces no records.

```
 Select * from Jet.LayoutListItemEntity_Default itemDefault
 Join  Jet.LayoutListEntity  b
 on itemDefault.UiKey = b.UiKey
 Left join (Select * from Jet.LayoutListItemEntity where DomainId =2) item
 on itemDefault.BindingPath = item.BindingPath
 where item.DomainId is null
 and b.DomainId = 2


 Select * from Jet.LayoutListItemEntity_Default itemDefault
 Join  Jet.LayoutListEntity  b
 on itemDefault.UiKey = b.UiKey
 Left join Jet.LayoutListItemEntity  item
 on itemDefault.BindingPath = item.BindingPath
 where item.DomainId is null
 and item.DomainId = 2
 and b.DomainId = 2
```

The primary difference is that one puts the `item.DomainId = 2` at the end, instead of in it's own select. It seems to me they would produce the same results.

Greg

Comment: Any reason as to the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These conditions are mutually exclusive:

```
where item.DomainId is null
 and item.DomainId = 2
```

`item.DomainID` can't simultaneously be `NULL` and `2`

You can move the errant where criteria to the `JOIN` criteria:

```
Select * from Jet.LayoutListItemEntity_Default itemDefault
 Join  Jet.LayoutListEntity  b
 on itemDefault.UiKey = b.UiKey
 Left join Jet.LayoutListItemEntity  item
 on itemDefault.BindingPath = item.BindingPath
    and item.DomainId = 2
 where item.DomainId is null
 and b.DomainId = 2
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize you could put criteria like that in a join.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` criteria is messed up in the 2nd query -- to make those statements the same, move the `and item_DomainId = 2` to the `JOIN`.

```
 Select * from Jet.LayoutListItemEntity_Default itemDefault
     Join  Jet.LayoutListEntity  b
         on itemDefault.UiKey = b.UiKey
     Left join Jet.LayoutListItemEntity  item
         on itemDefault.BindingPath = item.BindingPath and item.DomainId = 2
 where item.DomainId is null
     and b.DomainId = 2
```